# Paging PFQueryTableViewController automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

My goal is to setup the pagination with a `PFQueryTableViewController`. I would be satisfied with one of these solutions:

- 1, Paging the table view automatically. As in instance, if `objectsPerPage = 10` the `tableView` loads the next 10 objects when the actual row is the 10. row and so on.
- 2, Paging with a "load more cell" `UITableViewCell`. As I see it is the popular solution, so I would also love this variation.

Actually I'm getting no errors when I try the second solution, it just simply doesn't work. I've added a new cell on the Storyboard and created a class for it, and checked the AnyPic and other related codes as a starting point. As I see I should display the `LoadMoreCell` cell when the number of the rows are less than the `objects.count`. I tried it several ways, but nothing works, I can't display the `LoadMoreCell` anyway.

Here's my try:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (indexPath.row < self.objects.count) {
        NSLog(@"THE NUMBER OF ACTUAL ROW %d", indexPath.row);
        NSLog(@"cell tapped");

    } else  { 

        // load more
        [self loadNextPage];
        NSLog(@"LOAD NEXT PAGE");

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *LoadMoreCellIdentifier = @"loadmore";
    LoadMoreTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LoadMoreCellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[LoadMoreTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:LoadMoreCellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.loadMoreLabel.text = @"LOAD MORE CELLS";
        NSLog(@"NO CELL");
          }

    return cell;
}
```

The other part of my implementation is the last code part of the question.

***My original question covers my attempts with the first (paging automatically ) variation.***

**My original question:**

I have a working `PFQueryTableViewController`, but I'm unable to setup the pagination for it. My plan is simple, I want to load the next page when the user scrolled to the bottom of the table view. If the table displays 10 item/page I would like to display the next 10 item when the 10. cell appeared.

Actually I'm detecting when the user reached the bottom of the table and then call `[self loadNextPage]` for the new items, but the app crashes with this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 10
>   from section 0 which only contains 10 rows before the update'

I don't really understand  this issue, because the datasource (an array) has more than 40 objects that can be loaded.

Here's how I manage the method call (pagination is enabled at `initWithCoder`)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = aScrollView.bounds;
    CGSize size = aScrollView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = aScrollView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;
    float reload_distance = 10;
    if(y > h + reload_distance) {
        NSLog(@"load more rows");
        [self loadNextPageInTable];
    }
}

-(void) loadNextPageInTable {

     [self loadNextPage];
    NSLog(@"NEW PAGE LOADED");
}
```

And here is the table view setup

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"followClass";
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;
        self.objectsPerPage = 10;
    }
    return self;
}


- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
        return nil;
    }

    PFQuery *followQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"self.parseClassName"];
    [followQuery whereKey:@"followed" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    return query;

}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"followCell";
    FeedTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.followLabel.text = object[@"username"];
    cell.avatar.file = object[@"image"];
    [cell.avatar loadInBackground];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: @Yan I'm not sure that it crashes at `[self loadNextPage]`, because I have an `NSLog` in the `queryForTable` that appears in the log after the  `NSLog(@"load more rows");`. So I think the `queryForTable` gets called. No, there is no option for deleting rows. It works if I comment it out.

Comment: Would you be able to post more code.  Possibly from queryForTable to debug further and - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: Everything looks good.  With this code you see all the objects in the tableview and not 10?  if you comment out [self loadNextPageInTable]; and it doesn't crash do u see pagination?

Comment: When you load the table do you see only 10 objects or all of your data?

Comment: Let me know if you want to switch to chat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that works in my test project.  I do get the error that you get when `numberOfRowsInSection` is not commented out.   I do see load more cell but it automatically loads the rest of the cells let me know if that helps

```
#import "ParseDataTableViewController.h"

@implementation ParseDataTableViewController


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Custom the table

        // The className to query on
        //self.parseClassName = @"ParseTest";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style

        // The title for this table in the Navigation Controller.
        self.title = @"Test";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 15;
    }
    return self;
}




- (IBAction)nextPage:(id)sender
{
    [self loadNextPageInTable];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = aScrollView.bounds;
    CGSize size = aScrollView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = aScrollView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;
    float reload_distance = 15;
    if(y > h + reload_distance) {
        NSLog(@"load more rows");
        [self loadNextPageInTable];
    }
}

-(void) loadNextPageInTable {

    [self loadNextPage];
    NSLog(@"NEW PAGE LOADED");
}


- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {


    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name BEGINSWITH 't'"];
    PFQuery *followQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ParseTest" predicate:predicate];


    return followQuery;

}

/*-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.objects.count;
}*/



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DataCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = object[@"Name"];

    return cell;

}



@end
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't works, I get the same error. I think the query loads all of the results, if you don't set a limit and in this case I didn't limited the number of the results. Maybe the problem is the cells can't load the next 25 objects. Don't have an idea.

Comment: What if you add self.paginationEnabled = YES; which is default and comment out the whole - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView  method to see if you get the default pagination working

Comment: Doesn't help. Nothing happens, if I also call the loadNextPage I get the same error.

Comment: Do you see all of your data or just 10 objects?  Also do you see a row says  next page or something

Comment: I see all not just the per page value.

Comment: Can you update the question with code that you have now with limit set.  Try to set self.objectsPerPage = 7; and see if the error is different

Comment: I've updated my questions, it contains my new attempts. Unfortunately setting the objects to 10 doesn't helped.

Comment: I've tried it earlier with +1 row, got this error `'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`.

Comment: The question is are you seeing all of your data or only 10 rows.  change the self.objectsPerPage = 3; and return self.objects.count + 1; and see what happens

Comment: I think something is disabling pagination and you see all of the rows.

Comment: Also in queryForTable you have PFQuery *followQuery = .... and then you are returning query is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the query and everything else is working perfectly. I can display everything except the next pages

Comment: But in the tableview do you see all the results or just 10?  Does self.objectsPerPage = 10; work?

Comment: No :(. Just found this today [link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/blob/master/ParseUI/Classes/QueryTableViewController/PFQueryTableViewController.m) It looks promising,but didn't have time to try it today.

Comment: Let me know if u still having issues.  I created a parse project that works i would post the code if needed.

Comment: For which version? I'm fighting with the second one, but can't figure it out. I can't display the load more cell anyway.

Comment: I was actually able to reproduce your error.  Comment out the numbersOfRowsInSection and see if you get the error.

Comment: I updated my answer that i just tested with parse and it worked. I am not exactly sure why having numberOfRowsInSection crashes the program.  Could be something with number of rows and load more cell.

Comment: The IBAction does something?

Comment: Sorry forget about the IBAction.  I was just testing the loadnextpage if pressed by a button and not with the code.

Comment: I think the key to the error is the numberOfRowsInSection should not be overloaded.  Somehow that crashes the app with your error.  You have to create custom load more cell if needed

Comment: You can return a custom sell with just a activity indicator until the data loads

Comment: Yan, thank you very much, I really appreciate your help. It seems it's working. Just one more question, it's not a problem, that I'm not using the numberOfRowsInSection anymore? It can't lead to bad behavior or any crashes? What do you think?

Comment: I don't think there should be a problem. PFQueryTableViewController implements it otherwise it wouldn't work. It will return the correct number of objects.

Comment: Such an amazing lightweight solution. I couldn't make it crash so I think it will work. Did you experienced anything in your demo that I should care about?

Comment: I used such a solution in my app and haven't had any issues with parse.  I was just trying to figure out why having numberOfRowsInSection is an issue but couldn't.  You just have to work with the load more cell if you want to leave it default or customize it.  The only thing i can think of.

Comment: check out - (PFTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  to customize the cell https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/tableView:cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:

Comment: It's for the loading cell? Actually it has just a "Load more" label on a white bg. I've tried to edit it's color in IB, but nothing happened.

Comment: use this method and return your custom load more cell.  Let me know if it doesn't work i'll post the code a little later

Comment: Gonna try. Thanks again!!

Comment: I've just discovered a little bug, when I segue back to the table view's VC from another VC, the table view jumps back to the 10. object, doesn't matter if it was on the 2. or 4. page. Do you have any idea how could I avoid that?

Comment: I checked the app where i am using this solution and it's not going back.  Make sure you are not reloading the table when u segue back.    Somewhere in viewwillappear or something.  Let me know

Comment: You are right. I reloaded the table in viewWillAppear, removed it and works but it propounds another issue. I reloaded it there because I would like to load the new objects everytime when the VC is opened from a tab bar. Do you think implementing an if statement in viewWillAppear could be a working solution - that doesn't let to reload the table when we navigating back with segue -.?

Comment: I am not sure if u can differentiate in the viewWillAppear if you are coming back from segue or clicking on tab bar.  I don't know anything about the app that you are working on but i am not sure as far as usability reloading everytime you click on the tab bar.  What if a user scroll way down and few pages switch tabs and then it will reload.  I guess there should be away to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

In your cell creation you've got no way for the tableview to create a new cell if one does not exist already.

Create a new cell when one does not exist from the dequeuing mechanism:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"followCell";
FeedTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//adds new cell if one does not exist already
if (!cell) {
    cell = [FeedTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //TODO: edit cell details 
}


cell.followLabel.text = object[@"username"];
cell.avatar.file = object[@"image"];
[cell.avatar loadInBackground];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo app of first solution. Here you have [Demo](https://github.com/matkuznik/MKPaginationTableViewController). I didn't use `PFQueryTableViewController` (just UIKit) but I think there will no problem with this. In this demo all data are generated locally and to simulate downloading time, I was added a timer with 5s interval.

The error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 10 from section 0 which only contains 10 rows before the update'`

means that you are trying remove item with indexPath.row = 10, but there is no item on this position. The rows are counted from 0 so 10'th (in this case last one) item have indexPath.row = 9.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PFQueryTableViewController, but here is adapted working solution from one of my previous projects:

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // totalObjectsCount - you need somehow to get this value, to stop loading next objects after you show all
    if (self.objects.count < self.totalObjectsCount) {
        return self.objects.count + 1;
    } else {
        return self.objects.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    if (self.objects.count < self.totalObjectsCount
            && indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1) {
        LoadMoreCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LoadMoreCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;

    } else {
        // better if you use [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:] instead of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier
        FeedTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FollowCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.followLabel.text = object[@"username"];
        cell.avatar.file = object[@"image"];
        [cell.avatar loadInBackground];

        return cell;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.objects.count < self.totalObjectsCount
            && indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1) {
        // isLoadingMoreData - BOOL value, which indicating, that you already fetching new objects, we don't wanna make same multiple requests
        if (!self.isLoadingMoreData) {
            // loadMoreData - function, where you load more objects
            [self loadMoreData];
        }
    }
}
```